# How to use the default HTML email template when sending an email from a plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, templating, emails, classes

On `/admin/settings/email`, when the **HTML Email Template field** is set to a valid template, all system messages are sent using it. They inject the content of the messages inside the `{% block main %}{{body}}{% endblock %}` variable.

From a custom plugin, `setHtmlBody` doesn't inject the content inside it. It takes its value as the whole template value instead of only replacing the `{{body}}` variable.

Example:

```
<?php 

use craft\mail\Message;

$message = new Message();
$message->setTo('john@doe.com');
$message->setSubject("Hello world.");
$message->setHtmlBody("Hello world.");
$message->send();
```

How can I send this email using the custom HTML email template specified in my CP **Email Settings**?

I could copy-paste the whole file content of my custom template inside the setHtmlBody, but it doesn't seems to be a clean way...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are different ways

#### Extending the E-mail template in your template

This could be your email template `emails/_someMail`

```twig
{% extends 'path/of/your/layout-same-as-you-inserted-in-your-cp' %}

{% block main %}Hello World{% endblock %}
```

And in your PHP file

```PHP
use craft\mail\Message;

$message = new Message();
$message->setTo('john@doe.com');
$message->setSubject("Hello world.");
$message->setHtmlBody(Craft::$app->getView()->renderTemplate('emails/_someMail'));
$message->send();
```

#### Render the correct template from the beginning

You can do exactly the same as Craft does in it's function - but I would suggest the first way

```PHP
$systemMessage = Craft::$app->getSystemMessages()->getMessage('test_email', $message->language);
$subjectTemplate = $systemMessage->subject;
$textBodyTemplate = $systemMessage->body;

// Use the site template mode
$view = Craft::$app->getView();
$templateMode = $view->getTemplateMode();
$view->setTemplateMode($view::TEMPLATE_MODE_SITE);

// Use the message language
$language = Craft::$app->language;
if ($message->language !== null) {
    Craft::$app->language = $message->language;
}

$settings = Craft::$app->getSystemSettings()->getEmailSettings();
$variables = ($message->variables ?: []) + [
        'emailKey' => $message->key,
        'fromEmail' => $settings->fromEmail,
        'fromName' => $settings->fromName,
    ];

// Render the subject and textBody
$subject = $view->renderString($subjectTemplate, $variables);
$textBody = $view->renderString($textBodyTemplate, $variables);

// Is there a custom HTML template set?
if (Craft::$app->getEdition() === Craft::Pro && Craft::$app->getMailer()->template) {
    $template = Craft::$app->getMailer()->template;
} else {
    // Default to the _special/email.html template
    $view->setTemplateMode($view::TEMPLATE_MODE_CP);
    $template = '_special/email';
}

$e = null;
try {
    $htmlBody = $view->renderTemplate($template, array_merge($variables, [
        'body' => Template::raw(Markdown::process($textBody)),
    ]));
} catch (TemplateLoaderException $e) {
    // Clean up before throwing
}

// Set things back to normal
Craft::$app->language = $language;
$view->setTemplateMode($templateMode);

if ($e !== null) {
    throw $e;
}

$message
    ->setSubject($subject)
    ->setHtmlBody($htmlBody)
    ->setTextBody($textBody);
```

Comment: Thank you so much Robin. I always appreciate your relevant answers.

Comment: SO AWSM - thanks heaps